# How to Adjust container height according to the text height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a flutter application where I am trying to add a container and it's child text.
I want the container to take as much height as the text requires. But instead it takes the height specified.

Following is my code:

```
class ChangePassword extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
  _ChangePasswordState createState() =>
      _ChangePasswordState();
}

class _ChangePasswordState extends State<ChangePassword> {
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldkey,
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23),
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  child: Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  image: NetworkImage(imageurl)),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 25,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.lightBlue[900],
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                Text(email),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 2,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
                                      size: 12,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'View Profile',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
                          ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Positioned(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
                    top: 0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Color(0xff002060),
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  _scaffoldkey.currentState.openDrawer();
                                },
                                child: new Container(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.menu,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        0.04,
                                  ),
                                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                'Profile',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.16,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.14,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.14,
                          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.white),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: DecoratedBox(
                              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                        'https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/416x416/filters%3Aformat%28jpg%29/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fimageserve%2F5f4ebe0c87612dab4f12a597%2F0x0.jpg%3Fbackground%3D000000%26cropX1%3D292%26cropX2%3D3684%26cropY1%3D592%26cropY2%3D3987',
                                      ))),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                              child: Text(
                                'Bill Gates',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontFamily: 'Calibri'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.24,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.165,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                        child: Text(
                          'Bill Gates welcomes you. Welcome to Microsoft. It gives me immense pleasure to announce Josh Hazlewood as it\'s new CEO. It is always immense pleasure to work with them. looking foward to have a great time with him.',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Calibri'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
                ],
              )),
              
            ],
          ),
        ));

}
```

Following is the image:

[image]

I want the container that contains the text below 'Bill Gates' to be wrapped according to the information entered there.

The whole container should decrease as I am planning to add widgets below this customised appbar, so is there any way I can achieve this?

I tried to use flexible but it did not work. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Try using FittedBox

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.. can you suggest me something else please

Comment: Instead of Container, use Expanded widget that will take full height

Comment: I used expanded there, but the screen is coming blank after using it

Comment: You cannot use expanded inside listview

Comment: But I am not using listview

Comment: I changed some code and also used expanded but now it does wrap the text, it comes in a single horizontal line. How to wrap it now?

Comment: You cannot use Expanded inside SingleChildScrollView also, Expanded is used for fixed screen and SingleChildScrollView is used for scrolling screen

Comment: But I will be using more widgets below so I will have to use SingleChildScrollView

Comment: What do you want to create? I mean what kind of screen do you want to create?

Comment: It is basically an edit profile scren

Answer (score 9):

Use fitted box:-

```
FittedBox(
   fit:BoxFit.fitHeight,
   child:Text("Your text"),
),
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.. can you suggest me something else please

Comment: This worked for me very well. Thanks for the Tip. I upvoted your answer as well.

Comment: @RandikaVishman glad to know it worked for you

Comment: text is comming in single line.....rest of the text is not vsisible...

Answer (score 7):

Do not provide the height of the container and it will adjust automatically.

Comment: This answer helped, all the contents of the Container were no more overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

@Ankit,

**Culprit:** 
As you mentioned, the `Container` widget is intended to take the width and height you explicitly specify, so it does what you tell it to do.

What you should have done in the above case is avoid specifying the height for that `Container` which contains the `Text` widget as follows.

**Change this code section from:**

```
             Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.24,
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.165,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                    child: Text(
                      'Bill Gates welcomes you. Welcome to Microsoft. It gives me immense pleasure to announce Josh Hazlewood as it\'s new CEO. It is always immense pleasure to work with them. looking foward to have a great time with him.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Calibri'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

To the following code, where I have removed specifying the `height` property of the container:

```
           Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.24,
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.165,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.height,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                    child: Text(
                      'Bill Gates welcomes you. Welcome to Microsoft. It gives me immense pleasure to announce Josh Hazlewood as it\'s new CEO. It is always immense pleasure to work with them. looking foward to have a great time with him.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Calibri'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

By doing that, and wrapping the `Container` within a `FittedBox`, that varying text length `Text` widget will cause it to adjust its height accordingly.

Following part is important here:

```
               child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.height,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) to wrap the height of the text widget like this

```
Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'This text will determine the height of the row item',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```